# Is there a way to change existing project type from ASP.NET Web Application to ASP.NET MVC Application in VS 2008?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

So Visual Studio offers MVC content in context menus for "Add View", etc...

Sure, i can create a new MVC Web Application project type and move the files from the  non-MVC one there, but is there a way to change the project type without doing that step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no conversion tool I know of but it should be fairly simple with a text editor.  Create a new MVC Web application.  Open both project files in a text editor and copy the set of file entries from the old project into the new one.  Of course don't over-write the existing file entries that the new one would have create for you.

It will be a bit of mess though including both in the same app.  You will have to be careful with the routing configuration.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the project file,
replacing the <ProjectTypeGuids> in Web Application .cproj with the ones from MVC Application .cproj did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean some sort of wizard or tool to convert from a web forms app to MVC? No, there is no such tool in VS. It would be extremely hard to do as the architectures are quite different I'm afraid.

Comment: No, here i'm asking how to make Visual Studio just recognize the project as MVC one, i wouldn't trust a wizard changing the app architecture =)